# FabricJS is not support russian letters

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a trouble with FabricJS. When I create a russian text with follow constructor, I have no russian text only symbol '!'.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
var textObject = new fabric.Text('Привет!', {
                originX: 'center',
                originY: 'center',
                left: zone.left,
                top: zone.getCenterPoint().y,
                textAlign: 'center',
                fill: finalFill,
                stroke: '#000',
                strokeWidth: bezel,
                fontSize: fontSize,
                spacing: 5,
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontStyle: 'normal'
            });
```

Comment: Does your font support the cyrillic alphabet?

Comment: Are you using fabricjs 2.0?

Comment: if the font does not support cyrillic you should fallback on the system font it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked your example. It looks good.
Generally, the Russian text shouldn't be a problem, because we use it in our project. I didn't see any problems with it.

What can I guess:
1. Your left and top values are so, that text is outside of the canvas, and you see only the symbol "!".
2. Other, but hardly - some of your variables have wrong values. Try to set values, as in my example (I've tested it with fabric 2.0.3 and 1.7.22).

https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene_Ilyin/o2drxd0L/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var textObject = new fabric.Text('Привет!', {
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  textAlign: 'center',
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: '#000',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fontSize: 20,
  spacing: 5,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontStyle: 'normal'
});

canvas.add(textObject);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

For me it is rendered like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot!